# Issue with starting GNOME

Tags: arch-linux, gnome

I am currently running Arch kernel 4.13.12-1 and I am unable to login to GNOME. After I select the user and type the password the desktop fails to load. Instead I come to a textured grey screen and I can't move my mouse. (I am unable to upload an image because SE complains that it is too large). My mouse is always located in the center an I am unable to move it and the keyboard doesn't appear to work.

This happened after I was trying to resolve an issue with slow booting up. I ran the following code [from here](https://superuser.com/a/554343) in an attempt to fix these issues:

```
sudo -i
echo N> /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
echo "options drm_kms_helper poll=N">/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
```

After I made this change, and restarted my computer, I have had the symptoms mentioned above.

In order to try fixing this I logged into root. Logging into root went fine (desktop background appeared, mouse and keyboard worked). I then looked at `sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll` noticed it still said `Y` and even after using `sudo` I didn't have permission to change it.

I then attempted to change `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf`. First I deleted the line:

```
options drm_kms_helper poll=N
```

Nothing happened, still had the same symptoms. I also tried changing it to:

```
options drm_kms_helper poll=Y
```

Still the same symptoms. Any help would be appreciated on how to fix this issue. If you need more information please ask.

As for @jasonwryan response, here is what I dug up about Wayland in `jounralctl`:

```
Nov 23 12:02:50 christophersumnicht gnome-shell[415]: Connection to xwayland lost
Nov 23 12:02:50 christophersumnicht gsd-keyboard[517]: gsd-keyboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1024.
Nov 23 12:02:50 christophersumnicht gdm[358]: Tried to look up non-existent conversation gdm-launch-environment
Nov 23 12:02:50 christophersumnicht gdm[358]: Freeing conversation 'gdm-launch-environment' with active job
```

And this:

```
Nov 23 12:41:57 christophersumnicht systemd-coredump[810]: Process 464 (Xwayland) of user 120 dumped core.

                                                           Stack trace of thread 464:
                                                           #0  0x00007f89048848a0 raise (libc.so.6)
                                                           #1  0x00007f8904885f09 abort (libc.so.6)
                                                           #2  0x000055d928f9bb9a OsAbort (Xwayland)
                                                           #3  0x000055d928fa16b3 n/a (Xwayland)
                                                           #4  0x000055d928fa24d5 FatalError (Xwayland)
                                                           #5  0x000055d928e2dbaf n/a (Xwayland)
                                                           #6  0x000055d928f99711 n/a (Xwayland)
                                                           #7  0x000055d928f925bb WaitForSomething (Xwayland)
                                                           #8  0x000055d928f5e3c3 n/a (Xwayland)
                                                           #9  0x000055d928f62660 n/a (Xwayland)
                                                           #10 0x00007f8904870f6a __libc_start_main (libc.so.6)
                                                           #11 0x000055d928e2d20a _start (Xwayland)

                                                           Stack trace of thread 466:
                                                           #0  0x00007f8904c1538d pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (libpthread.so.0)
                                                           #1  0x00007f88fe33ca64 n/a (swrast_dri.so)
                                                           #2  0x00007f88fe33c8b8 n/a (swrast_dri.so)
                                                           #3  0x00007f8904c0f08a start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
                                                           #4  0x00007f890494647f __clone (libc.so.6)

                                                           Stack trace of thread 467:
                                                           #0  0x00007f8904c1538d pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (libpthread.so.0)
                                                           #1  0x00007f88fe33ca64 n/a (swrast_dri.so)
                                                           #2  0x00007f88fe33c8b8 n/a (swrast_dri.so)
                                                           #3  0x00007f8904c0f08a start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
                                                           #4  0x00007f890494647f __clone (libc.so.6)

                                                           Stack trace of thread 468:
                                                           #0  0x00007f8904c1538d pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (libpthread.so.0)
                                                           #1  0x00007f88fe33ca64 n/a (swrast_dri.so)
                                                           #2  0x00007f88fe33c8b8 n/a (swrast_dri.so)
                                                           #3  0x00007f8904c0f08a start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
                                                           #4  0x00007f890494647f __clone (libc.so.6)

                                                           Stack trace of thread 465:
                                                           #0  0x00007f8904c1538d pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (libpthread.so.0)
                                                           #1  0x00007f88fe33ca64 n/a (swrast_dri.so)
                                                           #2  0x00007f88fe33c8b8 n/a (swrast_dri.so)
                                                           #3  0x00007f8904c0f08a start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
                                                           #4  0x00007f890494647f __clone (libc.so.6)
```

Still not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Read your journal to find out why wayland is not starting.

Comment: @jasonwryan Hello, I guess you mean `journalctl` correct? I went in and search for wayland on Nov 23 and found a couple errors. I tried googling for them and wasn't able to find anything too helpful. Any thoughts?

Comment: Still not exactly sure what caused it, but clearing GNOME settings fixed it...